# When importing wallet by mnemonic phrase, how can I check whether it is correct or not?

Tags: web3.js, phantom, keypair, phantom-wallet, seed

For import wallet by mnemonic phrase i use next code:

```
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic_phrase, "");
const hd = HDKey.fromMasterSeed(seed.toString("hex"));
const keypair = Keypair.fromSeed(hd.derive(`m/44'/501'/0'/0'`).privateKey);
```

Additionally, I check the words in the phrase using the dictionary [bip-0039](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt).

In the phantom application, the seed phrase is somehow checked even if all the words of the seed phrase are in the dictionary.

How else can you check your seed phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like:

`if(bip39.validateMnemonic("test test test....junk") === true) { // do things }`

Comment: `bip39.ValidateMnemonic` should be `bip39.validateMnemonic`